# Resolve conflicts in favor of our/their keeping unconflicting changes

Tags: git, git-checkout, merge-conflict-resolution

`git checkout --theirs .` for example just takes the whole "theirs" file.

I search for a way to use "ours" or "theirs", but only for conflicts, as if by always removing the respective other part and the conflict markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, *before* you start the `git merge` operation, choose just that, using the `-X` options.  These options<sup>1</sup> allow you to choose to have "ours" or "theirs" override during low level (inside-a-file) conflicts, without affecting the merging of non-conflicting changes from both sides.

If you've already started the merge and resolved some conflicts, aborting the merge and restarting with `-X ours` or `-X theirs` is painful.  It's also unnecessary, because Git provides a separate command, `git merge-file`, that performs the three-way merge on a single set of three input files.

Hence, suppose you've started a merge, and it had three conflicts and stopped.  If you ran `git status` at this point you'd see those three files as unmerged.  So, you manually merged one of the three files, and started on the second and then thought: *Wait, I'd like to just have Git do this for me.*

What you can do at this point is stop resolving the work-tree file manually.  Exit any editor you're in, back to the command line.  For the second of the three files, extract all three inputs:

```
git show :1:file.ext > file.BASE
git show :2:file.ext > file.OURS
git show :3:file.ext > file.THEIRS
```

You now have the three inputs that Git tried, and failed, to merge on its own.  Git's attempt at merging the three is in `file.ext`; the three inputs are in these three files named `.BASE`, `.OURS`, and `.THEIRS`.

You can now invoke `git merge-file` and pass it `--ours` or `--theirs` to choose our or their changes where there are conflicts:

```
git merge-file --ours file.OURS file.BASE file.THEIRS
```

The resulting merge is written back to `file.OURS`.  Inspect it and see if you like the result; if so, rename it to `file.ext` and `git add file.ext` to mark this file resolved.  Remove the `file.BASE` and `file.THEIRS` copies that are cluttering your work-tree.

You have one remaining unresolved file.  Repeat the three extraction commands and the `git merge-file` command on those three copies of that one remaining file.

(There ought to be a user-oriented Git command that does all this for you, but there isn't.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I call them "eXtended options" or "eXtended strategy options" to account for the letter `X`.  The Git documentation just calls them "strategy-options", which is confusing because the `-s` option selects the strategy and hence is the strategy option.  The `-X` arguments are thus the strategy-option options, distinct from the strategy option.  ("Clear as mud", as they say.)  Saying that `-s` is the strategy option and `-X` supplies eXtended options just seems a lot less confusing.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I looked for. I couldn't use `-X`, because I wanted to deal with conflicts on an individual basis.